# How to code this function elegantly in Scala?

Tags: scala

Suppose I have the following classes:

```
case class Field(name: String, default: String)
case class Type(name: String, fields: Set[Field])
case class Info(name: String, type: Type, values: Map[Field, String])
```

Obviously for any `info:Info`

```
info.values.keySet == info.type.fields
```

Suppose also I have an `info:Info` and a `newType:Type` so that

```
info.type.name == newType.name
```

Now I need to create a `newInfo:Info` given `info: Info` and `newType: Type` so that:

```
1. newInfo.type == newType
2. newInfo.values.keySet = newType.fields
3. for each newField in newType.fields if !info.type.fields.contains(newField)
      newInfo.values(newField) == newField.default
```

I wonder how to code a function to create `newInfo` simply and elegantly:

```
def makeNewInfo(info: Info, newType: Type): Info = {
   assert info.type.name == newType.name
   ... // ???
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing you want to copy all the data from `info` into `newInfo`? Will all the fields always be present in `newInfo`?

Comment: Only the fields that present in `newType`. If `info` contains field `f`, which _does not_ present in `newType,` then `newInfo` should not contain `f` either.

Comment: Note that if `info` does not contain field `f1`, which _does_ present in `newType`, then `newInfo` should contain `f1` with its default value.

Comment: What about `newInfo.name`? Should it be the same as `info.name`?

Comment: Yes. newInfo.name == info.name.

Comment: I think it's better if you explain in words what is the ultimate goal of the function, instead of describing through the code. Please note that Scala is functional not imperative, also some of the things you describe (as in line 3) are frankly incomprehensible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val droppedFields = info.type.fields -- newType.fields
val addedFields = newType.fields -- info.type.fields
info.copy(values = info.values -- droppedFields ++ addedFields.map(f => (f, f.default))(collection.breakOut))
```